# YUI DataTable with dynamically load column def

Tags: spring-mvc, datatable, yui

I am doing a project with frontend using YUI data table to display some data. And I am using Spring MVC framework, the controller will get the data from database and return it in JSON format to the view.

My data source is a url that returns JSON data. But, since the JSON data is generated from data I extracted from data base. So the column number of the datatable is not fixed.

Is there a way that I can render a datatable with ColumnDef dynamically load from my Datasource?

Here is a way I tried with simple data in sample.jsp, but somehow it doesnt work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function() {
    YAHOO.example.Basic = function() {
        var myData = {"userInfo":[
                                   {"name":"Smith, Paul","age": "7","level":"","experience":"31","subtotal":"$0.00"},
                                   {"name":"Jones, Steve","age":"","level":"","experience":"60","subtotal":"$0.00"},
                                   {"name":"Dow, James","age":"","level":"","experience":"31","subtotal":"$0.00"},
                                   {"name":"Reid, Jake","age":"","level":"","experience":"6","subtotal":"$10.00"},
                                   {"name":"Smith, Nancy","age":"34","level":"3r","experience":"8","subtotal":"$0.00"}
                               ]};

    function getColumns(o, key) {
        var k, cols = [], value = o[key][0];

        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            for (k in value) {
                if (value.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    getColumns(value, k);
                    if (value.constructor !== Array) {
                        cols.push(k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return cols;
    }

    var myColumns = getColumns(myData, "userInfo");

    var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(myData);
    myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSARRAY;
    myDataSource.responseSchema = {
            fields: columns
        };
    var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("dataTable",
            myColumns, myDataSource, {initialLoad: true, caption: tableCaption});

    return {
        oDS: myDataSource,
        oDT: myDataTable
    };

}();
```

});

Comment: Hi! Would you mind commenting why you're not using YUI 3?

Comment: My boss said YUI 3 sucks so i am using YUI 2..